# SSIS | unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have deployed 2 SSIS package on a server. both fetches data from an Azure SQL Server. Both Packages have one execute SQL task and one for each loop container.
for package one, execute SQL task returns an object which has 2 columns and in case of package two, it returns an object which has 4 columns.

The problem is i am getting the error "**unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection**" for package 2 but not for package 1. Both packages are running fine from my local.

Answer (score 0):

you could use script select @@SERVERNAME; to verify the server is local or not, for remote server, it sometimes has connection issue.